# vuejs-datepicker Typeable Input submit delay

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have am using the Vuejs-datepicker

The problem I am having is I want to use a typable input as well as the datepicker, but when I type into this input field it fires the keyup event which triggers its v-on:selected event.

Meaning if I start typing in '2012-02-02' with it submits on ever key up.

Usually this would be easy to solve as you can use a .length but this vue component always hands back a Date that is parsed. So that won't work.

I have the idea to deconstruct the component and build my own but was hoping someone might have an idea for a different solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the Event Modifiers?

You could try to use then in @keyup, something like @keyup.prevent...

Se at, look for "Event Modifiers":
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html